# How to save annotated output from StanfordNLPCore to a string?

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, printwriter

My code takes in a string, annotates that string accordingly, and then sends the output to an OutputStream (prettyPrint sends the annotated string to System.out). I want to write it to a String rather than System.out but i cant seem to get it too work.

```
public void NERprint(String s) throws IOException {


  String output = "";
  PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);

// Add in sentiment
  Properties props = new Properties();
// parse, dcoref, sentiment
  props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner");

  StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

// Initialize an Annotation with some text to be annotated. The text is the argument to the constructor.
  Annotation annotation = new Annotation(s);

// run all the selected Annotators on this text
  pipeline.annotate(annotation);
 // this prints out the results of sentence analysis to file(s) in good formats

  pipeline.prettyPrint(annotation, out);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some sample code:

```
pipeline.annotate(annotation);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
pipeline.prettyPrint(annotation, baos);
String stringOutput = baos.toString();
```

Comment: thank you for keeping it short and sweet. worked perfectly